# Calculating elapsed time and saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to log in a Ruby app DB Table (MySQL Database), the time and date that an import script started, finished and how long the script took to execute.

The logging of the start time and finish time is easy enough, and I've got that working, however, I can't get it to save the runtime in the table, it just skips the field.

Here's the table structure from the Migration file

```
create_table :import_alls do |t|
  t.datetime :Import_Start_Time
  t.datetime :Import_Finish_Time
  t.time :Import_Duration


  t.timestamps
end
```

Here's my code ...

```
@script_start_time = Time.now
[... Script ...]
@script_finish_time = Time.now
@script_runtime = @script_finish_time - @script_start_time

import = ImportAll.new
    import.Import_Start_Time = @script_start_time # Saves correctly
    import.Import_Finish_Time = @script_finish_time # Saves Correctly
    import.Import_Duration = @script_runtime # Skips
    [... a few other fields to save ...] # All save correctly
import.save!

puts @script_runtime # Puts correct number of seconds as a line in the server log
```

Saved Results :

```
Import_Start_Time = Start Date & Time as expected
Import_Finish_Time = Finish Date & Time as expected
Import_Duration = NULL (expected duration expressed as HH:MM:SS)
```

So,

1. is a `time` field the correct type if field? or should it be `datetime` ?
2. how can I convert the @script_runtime value into a `time` field so it can be saved in the table ?

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: Just edited question to reflect its a MySQL databse

Comment: Are you sure that `@script_runtime` is not `nil`?

Comment: when I check the server log, the correct number of seconds is put by the `puts @script_runtime` line so yes, as sure as I can be

Comment: current value is `12.023267542`

Comment: Btw Ruby on Rails follows the Convention of Configuration paradigm and it has strong opinions about how things should be named. I advise following these conventions, otherwise, you will run in all kinds of nasty issues and need to reconfigure a lot. Some gem might not even work if your naming conventions are different from the Ruby community defaults.

Comment: What changes would you suggest @spickermann

Comment: Method names and attributes have `downcase_with_underscores` names – same for database column names.

Answer (score 1):

Could be some data type conversion issue:

```
2.6.3 :018 > t = Time.new(12.023267542)
=> 0012-01-01 00:00:00 +0053
```

Instead of `time`, I'd use an `integer` column to store the duration.

Comment: it is likely that that is what the problem is, however, I need it to be easily displayed as a time in the admin panel view.  If you can advise how I can do that, I can easily change the storage type.